# Get domain from URL without question mark

Tags: php, parse-url

Running `parse_url()` on :

This kind of URLs : `http://mondomom.com` extracts successfully `mondomom.com` and returns it as host.

This kind of URLs : `http://www.mondomom.com/?sdfdsfsd=dsdfsdf` extracts successfully `mondomom.com` and returns it as host.

But on this kind of URLs : `http://www.mondomom.com/sdasdasd/sdad` the `parse_url()` function can not find the domain. It seems that it is only designed to work with URL that have query strings in them

Is there a way to extract the correct domain from the latter ?

Comment: It works perfectly for me. `var_dump(parse_url('http://www.mondomom.com/sdasdasd/sdad'));` produces: `array(3) {
  'scheme' =>
  string(4) "http"
  'host' =>
  string(16) "www.mondomom.com"
  'path' =>
  string(14) "/sdasdasd/sdad"
}` What version of PHP are you using? Are you sure you're not seeing non-ASCII characters that just look like `/`, etc.?

Comment: Would try to explode / and var_dump a array of it, maybe.. and try a preg match for first part http:// getthis/